# jQuery Overlapping Elements causing Flickering

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I'm developing a "featured" section to a site. The idea being that when hovering over an element on the left it will trigger a fade-in of the right half.

This is working except where there is an overlap of elements (anywhere in the center in-between the red lines). It causes a flickering of the fade-in effect.

[image: Wireframe]

This is the feature HTML

```
<div id="feature">  
<div id="left-overlay">...Right</div>
<div id="left-feature"><h2>Left</h2></div>
<div id="right-overlay">...Left</div>
<div id="right-feature"><h2>Right</h2></div></div>
```

And this is the jQuery

```
$('div#left-feature').hover(function () {
    $('div#left-overlay').stop().css({'z-index' : '10'}).fadeTo('normal', 1);
}, function () {
    $('div#left-overlay').stop().fadeTo('normal', 0).css({'z-index' : '-10'});
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've added a link a demo of this code and its functionality - http://jsfiddle.net/jamescallaghan/7rLhS/

Comment: By adding z-index:1000 to the left and right feature divs, it seems to have stopped the flickering - http://jsfiddle.net/jamescallaghan/7rLhS/1/

Comment: If that solved it for you you might want to "answer your own question" and mark your own answer as the right one. It will make it easier for other people to find a resolution to this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is following:
while adding a z-index of 10 to the overlay div its placed above the hovering element (so you aint hovering anymore).

a solution could be to place the overlay divs inside the hovering divs:

```
<div id="feature">    

<div id="left-feature"><h2>Left</h2>
<div id="left-overlay">...</div>
</div>  


<div id="right-feature"><h2>Right</h2>
<div id="right-overlay">...</div>
</div>
```

then i dont see any flickering.

plus id code jquery in a different way (but your way is totally ok as well..)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("div#left-overlay, div#right-overlay").hide();

$('div#left-feature').hover(function() {
    $('div#left-overlay').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('div#left-overlay').hide();
});

$('div#right-feature').hover(function() {
    $('div#right-overlay').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('div#right-overlay').hide();
});
});
```

and in the css you then dont need:

```
display:block; /*its a div, and those have block n-e-ways*/
opacity:0; /*i do this via jquery, or you make display: none; (for those whithout js)*/
-moz-opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: -10; /*no need for swapping z-index*/
```

the boxes need to be placed different then, cause the position absolute then starts at the zero of the surrounding div but...